# Cannot use `\numexpr` in horizontal mode

Tags: errors, texlive, e-tex

I try to learn to work with `\numexpr` and have some trouble with the basics. etex_man has not been detailed enough to help in this case.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hi \numexpr 6 + 1 \relax
\end{document}
```

The error when I call pdflatex from TexLive is "You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode." Similar error if I switch to vertical or math mode.

So clearly I am missing something basic. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: You might want to read Chapter 7 of [*TeX by Topic*](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) which explains the different number types in TeX and in what context they may occur. `\numexpr` is added in e-TeX as a new alternative to `<internal integer>`. You find the extended grammar rules in the [e-TeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\numexpr` is an additional item that can be used in contexts where TeX is looking for a `<number>`.

It basically is an “unnamed counter register” as far as its syntax is concerned and is not allowed “bare”.

It essentially works like `\countX` (where `\countX` stands for an “unreachable” count register number) after this unnamed register is loaded with the value of the expression.

So just like you can't say `Hi \count232` to print the value stored in `\count232`, you cannot say

```
Hi \numexpr 6+1\relax
```

Just consider `\count232` and `\numexpr 6+1\relax` as referring to an *abstract number*, which exists independently of its representation. You need to access a representation of this abstract number:

```
Hi \number\count232

Hi \romannumeral\count232

Hi \number\numexpr 6+1\relax

Hi \romannumeral\numexpr 6+1\relax
```

Bare bones TeX only provides `\number` (for the decimal representation) and `\romannumeral` (for lowercase Roman numeral representation). Add-on packages may provide other representations.

Answer (score 11):

You need `\number` or `\the` in front of the expression: `\numexpr` works like a TeX `\count`. Alternatively, you could use the `xfp` package to provide a thin wrapper

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\number\numexpr 1 + 2 * 3 \relax

\the\numexpr 1 + 2 * 3 \relax

\inteval{1 + 2 * 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks--this certainly removed the error. Do you know why this is needed? I am not a TeX wiz, and Googling "the TeX" is unproductive...

Comment: @ZachBoyd Some commands are just not meant to be used in horizontal mode (typesetting): `\numexpr` is just one of those.